# Create views specific to each subfolder

Tags: sharepoint-online, view, subfolders

Have a sharepoint library folder with sub folders for different reports and documents. I'd like to create views (and possibly columns) that are unique to each of those sub folders.

I read an article saying to do this by creating a new content type called subfolder with with folder content type.
I did that and added it as a content to the library. Then created a subfolder and in the Folders section, choose show this view in subfolder content type.

But the view is still showing in all folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest replacing folders with document sets, 
with these you can filter the view by the document set metadata

a document set is no more than a folder that can store metadata.

Comment: Hey Mike thanks for the reply. Document sets wasn't showing in the site features however you did lead me in the right direction. There was a site feature called Metadata Navigation and Filtering which allows me to do a per-location view setting based on metadata in each list and library.

Answer (score 0):

The option Filtering and navigation by metadata should be active, with this option you resolved the problem?